# Data is extremely slow to load after joining sf object and tibble, what is going on?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

trying to use `dplyr::inner_join()` to join an `sf` object and a regular `tibble` object. Not sure why, but the data is extremely slow to load ( almost to a snails pace) after the join; the resulting table after the join is not very large ( 20 rows, 14 columns). What I mean by slow is that doing anything with this data including viewing it, plotting it, etc. takes forever to complete.

So I have the `sf` object which is some polygons and a unique ID for each, so there is only the geometry and those ID's stored in the data frame associated with the object. The tibble is not very large ( 51 rows, 13 variables).

```r
test_join <- sf_object %>%
 inner_join(tibble, by = c("Id" = "Id from tibble")
```

anyone ever experience this or know what is going?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the `sf` geometry is very complex? One suggestion is to simplify the object before joining if you don't need the full complexity: `rmapshaper::ms_simplify(sf_object) %>% inner_join...`

Comment: Can you give some example data to replicate your issue?

Comment: @Chris thanks I'll look into that

Comment: If the complexity of the geometry was the problem then the original `sf_object` might also be slow to work with and the `inner_join` would be an irrelevance. You can only be having 20 geometries from the `sf_object` in your output.